# How can I inject HTML into a page without affecting the current page's styles?

Tags: javascript, html, css, foundation

I am making page blocks for a third party to copy and paste into their CMS. These HTML page blocks use the foundation framework for styles, but sometimes when foundation is appended to the page it interferes with the rest of the page's styles. How do I prevent this? Is there another framework I can use that will inline all of the CSS or can I leverage a different framework to build this out?

Here is how I am doing it now.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.7.5/dist/js/foundation.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    const fs = document.createElement('link');
    fs.rel = 'stylesheet';
    fs.href = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.7.5/dist/css/foundation.min.css';
    fs.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fs);

    const fa = document.createElement('link');
    fa.rel = 'stylesheet';
    fa.href = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css';
    fa.integrity = 'sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==';
    fa.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    fa.referrerPolicy ='no-referrer';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fa);
</script>
<div class="grid-container padding-top-bottom">
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x align-middle">
        <div class="cell medium-6">
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="cell medium-6" style="padding-right:10px">
            <p>Some other text and images</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This ends up messing up some of the original sites's styles when pasted into an HTML block on some CMS's.

Comment: There are a few solutions. You can always modify the framework's CSS so all of the selectors are associated with a parent element that you attach to your code. For example, you could have a parent div with the class of sopkoCMS and modify all of the CSS selectors to work via .sopkoCMS .grid .. etc .. This will allow you to have custom selectors for your code.

Comment: isolate your content, e.g. create and fill a sandboxed iframe, or make your content a custom element and stick everything in a shadow dom.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shadow root, move to it your content and attach your styles to it:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.7.5/dist/js/foundation.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="module">

    const {children} = $shadow; // we add a shadow DOM to this element, get its children
    // create a shadow DOM root
    const $root = $shadow.attachShadow({mode:'open'}); 
    // move the children to the shadow root
    [...children].forEach(child => $root.appendChild(child));

    // attach the styles to the shadow root
    const fs = document.createElement('link');
    fs.rel = 'stylesheet';
    fs.href = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.7.5/dist/css/foundation.min.css';
    fs.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    $root.appendChild(fs);

    const fa = document.createElement('link');
    fa.rel = 'stylesheet';
    fa.href = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css';
    fa.integrity = 'sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==';
    fa.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    fa.referrerPolicy ='no-referrer';
    $root.appendChild(fa);
    
    
</script>
<div class="grid-container padding-top-bottom">
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x align-middle">
        <div class="cell medium-6">
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="cell medium-6" style="padding-right:10px">
            <p>Some other text and images</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="$shadow" class="grid-container padding-top-bottom">
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x align-middle">
        <div class="cell medium-6">
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="cell medium-6" style="padding-right:10px">
            <p>Some other text and images</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```